# Yoast review text of a custom page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have made a custom page with text in WordPress. If I try to analyze it with Yoast, it says '0 words'. Is there any other way to analyze it? Could I solve it with another plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. it is not possible with Yoast Plugin.

The only solution is just copy the all content of your template to page of WordPress and analyze that page.